# SQL performance issue local + remote database

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to select several 1000 rows from a remote database (where I can change nothing). I have (string) IDs to filter the needed data rows but I'm having performance issues.

Using a simple sql select I can retrieve the data in ~4 s.
`

```
SELECT
    myid,
    column2
FROM
    view1@remotedb
WHERE
    myid IN ( '1', '2', '3' )
```

`

Since I need to select several thousand rows I'm using a local database for the IDs to select.
`

```
SELECT /*+DRIVING_SITE(V1)*/ myid,
    column2
FROM
    view1@remotedb    v1,
    localdb           t1
WHERE
    v1.myid = t1.myid;
```

`
Unfortunately even for only 3 IDs in t1 the execution time increases to 3 min. Using driving_site or not makes no difference. Is there a way to increase the performance?

Comment: How many rows are in the remote table. Sometimes it's simpler to just copy all rows locally then you have a lot more options

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan? From a cursory research I would have expected DRIVING_SITE to help but I see you already use that.

Comment: It's probably seeking for each ID separately in the remote view and with bad network latencies that can be a performance killer. I would use Dynamic SQL and assemble batches of 900 IDs at a time to run the query. It's worth a try.

Comment: Another option is to create a procedure in the remote engine that receives all 10k ID in an array, store them in a local temp table, then queries/joins locally, and return a single result set. That could produce high performance query. However, it requires more development effort.

Comment: The remote database has several million entries. Copying it is not an option :/. Due to ORA-01039: insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view I cannot see the execution plan. Next week maybe someone with the priviliges can get more infos for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if keeping the localdb in the subquery helps.

```
SELECT
    myid,
    column2
FROM
    view1@remotedb
WHERE
    myid IN ( SELECT myid from localdb)
```

Comment: Using a subquery has the same performance (~3 min)

Answer (score -1):

In [this thread](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/1134588/slow-query-when-joining-local-table-to-remote-tables) on this same problem I found this little helpful bit:

> Hints require a  character after the "+".

You don't have a space between the + and DRIVING_SITE.

I am super confused by this thread as it seems people are claiming this is necessary as well as that it isn't (but in the end OP says it helped). But it's worth trying. Please check the execution plan to check whether it looks like the hint is honored. What you want to achieve is that t1 is sent to the remote db and the join performed there instead of v1 getting sent to your local db and joined there.

You find the documentation for the syntax [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#BABEGIJC).

Comment: Unfortunately the space(s) did not help. And I cannot see the execution plan due to ORA-01039: insufficient privileges on underlying objects of the view.
Next week maybe someone with the priviliges can get more infos.

Comment: That thread is incorrect - hints do not require a space after the `+`. For example, if your system allows parallelism, this hint doesn't have a space but still enables parallelism: `explain plan for select/*+parallel(8)*/*from all_users; select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` Changing arbitrary characters can change behavior if the previous query used some mechanism to force a specific execution plan. Changing a single character changes the SQL_ID (hash), and Oracle stops applying the plan control. This is why it's critical to read the *entire* explain plan, including the "Note" section.